# Blank or reusable List<t> outside If statement C#

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net

I can't inherit the idea of Nothing from Vb.net code. but I wish to declare  a list type in a if statement e.g.

```
Var LabourUnits;//does not work    

if (LabourLinesFor == "Quote")
{
    LabourUnits = context.QuoteLabourUnitsViews.Where(x => x.QuoteId == RelatedId).OrderBy(x => x.DisplayOrder).ToList();
    ShowDiscounts = context.QuoteLabourUnitsViews.Where(x => x.QuoteId == RelatedId && x.UnitDiscountExVat > 0).Any();
    VATPercent = default;
}
else if (LabourLinesFor == "Refund")
{
    LabourUnits = context.RefundLabourUnitsViews.Where(x => x.RefundId == RelatedId).ToList();
    VATPercent = context.RefundsViews.Where(x => x.RefundId == RelatedId).Select(x => x.Vatpercent).FirstOrDefault();
}

if(LabourUnits.Count > 0)
{
    //do something
}
```

as the type is declared in the if statement it does not feed out to the outer var, and therefore cannot be used. Is there a way of creating a blank or carrier List?
Updated
Have used a real example, in vb LabourUnits  could be declared as nothing but would then be accessible

further the VB -

```
Dim LabourUnits = Nothing
  If LabourLinesFor = "Quote" Then
            LabourUnits = dal.dc.QuoteLabourUnitsViews.Where(Function(x) x.QuoteID = RelatedID).OrderBy(Function(x) x.DisplayOrder).ToList
            ShowDiscounts = dal.dc.QuoteLabourUnitsViews.Where(Function(x) x.QuoteID = RelatedID And x.UnitDiscountExVat > 0).Any
            VATPercent = CType(Nothing, Decimal?)
        ElseIf LabourLinesFor = "Refund" Then
            LabourUnits = dal.dc.RefundLabourUnitsViews.Where(Function(x) x.RefundID = RelatedID).ToList
            VATPercent = dal.dc.RefundsViews.Where(Function(x) x.RefundID = RelatedID).Select(Function(x) x.VATPercent).FirstOrDefault
End If
If LabourUnits.Count > 0  Then
'do something
End If
```

---

Failed attempt...

```
 List<JobLabourUnitsView> jLabourUnits = new();
            List<QuoteLabourUnitsView> qLabourUnits=new();
            List<RefundLabourUnitsView> rLabourUnits = new();
            List<PartsOnlyLabourView> pLabourUnits = new();
            List<JobLabourUnitsView> prevLabourUnits = new();



        


            decimal? VATPercent = default;

            var ShowDiscounts = default(bool);

            if (Preview)
            {
               prevLabourUnits = GetPreviewLabourUnits();
            }
            else if (LabourLinesFor == "Job")
            {
                
                jLabourUnits = context.JobLabourUnitsViews.Where(x => x.JobId == RelatedId).OrderBy(x => x.DisplayOrder).ToList();
                ShowDiscounts = context.JobLabourUnitsViews.Where(x => x.JobId == RelatedId && x.UnitDiscountExVat > 0).Any();
                VATPercent = context.TblJobs.Where(x => x.JobId == RelatedId).Select(x => x.Vatpercent).FirstOrDefault();
               
            }

            else if (LabourLinesFor == "Quote")
            {
                qLabourUnits = context.QuoteLabourUnitsViews.Where(x => x.QuoteId == RelatedId).OrderBy(x => x.DisplayOrder).ToList();
                ShowDiscounts = context.QuoteLabourUnitsViews.Where(x => x.QuoteId == RelatedId && x.UnitDiscountExVat > 0).Any();
                VATPercent = default;
               
            }
            else if (LabourLinesFor == "Refund")
            {
               rLabourUnits = context.RefundLabourUnitsViews.Where(x => x.RefundId == RelatedId).ToList();
                VATPercent = context.RefundsViews.Where(x => x.RefundId == RelatedId).Select(x => x.Vatpercent).FirstOrDefault();
            }
            else if (LabourLinesFor == "PartsOnlySale")
            {
                pLabourUnits = context.PartsOnlyLabourViews.Where(x => x.PartsOnlySaleId == RelatedId).OrderBy(x => x.DisplayOrder).ToList();
                ShowDiscounts = context.PartsOnlyLabourViews.Where(x => x.PartsOnlySaleId == RelatedId && x.UnitDiscountExVat > 0).Any();
                VATPercent = context.TblPartsOnlySales.Where(x => x.PartsOnlySaleId == RelatedId).Select(x => x.Vatpercent).FirstOrDefault();
            }
            else if (LabourLinesFor == "CarSale")
            {

            }

            Object[] obj = {
        new { key = "0", value = jLabourUnits},
        new { key = "1", value = qLabourUnits},
        new { key = "2", value = rLabourUnits},
        new { key = "3", value = pLabourUnits},
         new { key = "4", value = prevLabourUnits}
    };

            int ticky = 0;
            Type mod;

            if(jLabourUnits.Count() > 0)
            {
                ticky = 0;
                mod = (Type)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(JobLabourUnitsView));
            }
            else if(qLabourUnits.Count() > 0)
            {
                ticky = 1;
                mod = (Type)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(QuoteLabourUnitsView));
            }
            else if(rLabourUnits.Count() > 0){
                ticky = 2;
                mod = (Type)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(RefundLabourUnitsView));
            }
            else if(pLabourUnits.Count() > 0){
                ticky = 3;
                mod = (Type)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(PartsOnlyLabourView));
            }
            else if(prevLabourUnits.Count() > 0){
                ticky = 4;
                mod = (Type)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(JobLabourUnitsView));
            }
            IList<mod> LabourUnits = obj[ticky];

            if (LabourUnits.Count() > 0)
                //do something
```

This is totally unpleasant and doesn't work but as you can see have tried lateral methods...

Comment: A variable has *a* type, fixed at compile time. You don't get to pick which type it's going to be at runtime, that's far too late. It's unclear what problem you're trying to solve though because you've focussed your question on a non-existent solution. (It's also unclear what `Nothing` has to do with it. The C# rough equivalent to it is `default`)

Comment: no you can't do it in C#

Comment: I need the object of a list without a type outside the if Statement so that I can reference it. The list(s) are created by Linq in the statement.

Comment: You could try `List<object> list;` and in your if-statement assign it like `list = new List<a>();`. But I wouldn't consider this as a solution. Can you explain what you are trying to do with more details?

Comment: What you are suggesting is not possible in VB either. Yes, the value of a variable can be `Nothing` in VB but it can be `null` in C#, which is the same thing. The variable still has to have a type in VB though, just as it does in C#. You could declare the variable as type `Object` and assign objects of different types to it in VB, but you can do that in C# too. I suspect that you're talking about having `Option Strict Off` and not specifying a type at all, but then it simply defaults to `Object`. VB won't help you any more than C# here.

Comment: You should have posted the vb.net code.  There is a way: `dynamic list;`

Comment: You can only do this when your `QuoteLabourUnitsView` and `RefundLabourUnitsView` types share a common base class or implement the same interface. Then you can declare the variable as `List<ILabourUnit>` and call `.ToList<ILabourUnit>()` on your queries.

Comment: Have tried dynamic no luck...

Comment: @CodeCaster unfortunately they are part of the Entity Framework, which I am trying to keep vanilla...

Comment: I'm not sure what that means. They're not part of Entity Framework, that's a library you use. If you mean they're generated entities, you can create partial classes in your own file and apply the new interface there. Ultimately a `List<object>` also does what you want, but then you can't do anything meaningful with its contents.

Comment: @CodeCaster tried List<object> then recasting, no luck! My terminology may be somewhat off as I'm a "hedge coder" i.e. self taught.

Comment: Like I said, your VB code is not doing the magic you think it is. `Dim LabourUnits = Nothing` is the same as `Dim LabourUnits As Object = Nothing`. You'd have to have `Option Strict Off` to do that and then you can use late binding later on, but that would be bad code anyway. If you really want to do that then you can use `dynamic` but I'd recommend against that. One option might be to declare the variable as type `IList`. That has a `Count` property and any `List<T>` can be assigned to it. You can also enumerate it using a `foreach` loop, but each item will be an `object` reference`.

Comment: @John  agreed the VB is a fluke, but it allows the variable list type to be assigned within the if statement. Not my code so cannot vouch for it. The C# var has to be assigned before you can use it.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever I believe the equivalence is exact, not just rough.

Comment: and yet the above VB is in production...must be Magic...you still have to declare the type with default (believe me I've tried).

Comment: That's because you've focused on the wrong part. The mechanism that allows VB to use multiple objects of different types for a variable declare as Object is what C# has as `dynamic`. Neither has anything, specifically, to do with `Nothing`, other than an inferred type.

Comment: I agree "LabourUnits" is not a list, but is cast as a list in the if statement, that is the functionality I am trying to replicate, but  var needs a type  pseudo code
Bucket -> 
if tap 1 water->
else tap 2 petrol->
pour Bucket

Bucket for petrol
if Tap 1 water - cannot supply petrol ->
else Tap 2 can fill Bucket ->
Can only ever pour petrol 

I am looking for something similar in C#
Nothing provides a Bucket

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @John suggested the way to go was *dynamic* after experimentation by casting it to *null* (having tried *getType* in various combinations) I was able to check for modification which was why I had rejected the method previously. Thank you all.

Answer (score 5):

As Damien pointed out, you need to specify the type. If you use 'var' keyword, you can't leave the variable uninitialized.

```
var list; // will not work, the type is not known
List<string> list2; // will work, the type is clear
```

In this case, I would create a `List<Interface>` or `List<AbstractClass>` and then depending on what I need, have the list contain one or another object of a class that implement this interface or inherit from the abstract class.

```
List<IFruit> fruits = new();
fruits.Add(new Apple());
fruits.Add(new Orange());

interface IFruit { }
class Apple : IFruit { }
class Orange : IFruit { }
```

Comment: Thank you I have tried something similar with limited success it is the legacy data that is flooring me at the moment!

Comment: but is there a way of getting an unassigned var a la the VB dim LabourUnits? I Could be totally barking up the wrong tree, but have tried arrays, dynamic and objects and don't wish to have reams of repeat code.

Comment: The way I understand your code, I would create an abstract class or an interface '(I)LabourUnitView', have 'RefundLabourUnitsView' and 'QuoteLabourUnitsView' inherit from it/implement it and declare the list:

List<LabourUnit> labourUnits or List<ILabourUnit> labourUnits;

This way it should be fine.

Also, if you want to have it unassigned, you can't use var, you need to specify the type.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure that you fully understand what's going on in the VB or the C#, so I'll go over it all.

In VB, `Option Strict` determines whether strict typing is enforced (`On`) or not (`Off`). `Option Strict Off` is the default, to make things easier for beginners and VB6 developers but a good VB.NET developer will turn it `On` immediately and leave it `On` in all but those cases where late-binding is required, e.g. Office Automation. Even then, it should be `On` at the project level and `Off` at the file level for only those files that require it. Partial classes should be used to keep the amount of code in those files to an absolute minimum.

With `Option Strict Off`, you can do this in VB:

```vb
Dim someVariable
```

In that case, `someVariable` defaults to type `Object`. That code is functionally equivalent to this:

```vb
Dim someVariable As Object
```

With `Option Strict On` and strict typing enforced, the second code snippet would be required.

With the introduction of `Option Infer`, variable data types can now be inferred from an initialising expression. Whether `Option Strict` is `On` or `Off`, with `Option Infer On` you can do this:

```vb
Dim someVariable = someExpression
```

and the data type of `someVariable` will be inferred from the type of `someExpression`, rather than defaulting to `Object`. In C#, the use of `var` works the same way, inferring the variable type from the initialising expression. This means that `var` only makes sense when there is such an expression. This is valid C# code: `Option Strict` is `On` or `Off`, with `Option Infer On` you can do this:

```cs
var someVariable = someExpression;
```

but this makes no sense:

```cs
var someVariable;
```

With `Option Strict Off` in VB, late binding is allowed. That means that the compiler will allow you to specify member access on an `Object` reference that it cannot confirm and it is up to you to ensure that the actual object at run time has the specified member. This is allowed with `Option Strict Off`:

```vb
Dim someVariable As Object = "Hello World"
Dim someOtherVariable

someOtherVariable = "Hello World"

Dim x Integer = someVariable.Length
Dim y Integer = someOtherVariable.Length
```

With `Option Strict On`, that code would not compile. In C#, you can get basically the same functionality using `dynamic`:

```cs
dynamic someVariable = "Hello World";
dynamic someOtherVariable;

someOtherVariable = "Hello World";

int x = someVariable.Length;
int y = someOtherVariable.Length;
```

Again, though, you should not be using `dynamic` all over the place because you can't be bothered to write good strongly-typed code. It should be used where it adds genuine value.

In your case, if the reason you want to use a single variable is to use the `Count` property then you can go for the lowest common denominator, which would be `ICollection`. Any `List<T>` can be assigned to a variable of that type, as can arrays and various other collections. `ICollection` exposes a `Count` property and it extends `IEnumerable`, so you can run a `foreach` loop over it too. If you use `IList` instead then you can also index the list to get or set an item as well as `Add`, `Remove` and so on.

Using any of those interfaces, each item will be an `Object` reference, so you cannot do anything that is specific to the item type. You could do anything with an item that wasn't common to all possible types anyway, which you could do if you were to have each item type implement the same interface.

If you want any more than that, you're going to have to explain what you actually want to achieve by using the same variable for different types of lists. You've shown the use of `Count` and I've covered that. is there anything relevant that you didn't actually explain in your question?

Comment: Thank you @user18387401 no not just the count the "dynamic" list is used later (as I said not my code) lots of for loops later on I'm lazy and was trying to avoid writing 4000 lines for each list...

Comment: As I understand the vb you are setting up a "space" then setting it to nothing, but crucially the "space" is still assigned an identity which is outside the if statement and can be filled inside(in much the same way as the JavaScript var) I know C# is strongly type I just hoped there was an equivalent "hole".

Comment: @aegsomweb, you still seem to think that VB is performing some magic here. It's not. In VB, you're simply declaring a variable of type `Object`. That's it, that's all. With `Option Strict Off`, you can access members of the referenced object that are not members of the `Object` type. C# can do the same using `dynamic`. Whatever you think you can do with VB, you can do with C#. The question is whether you should do what you think you want to do with VB. Probably not, but we can't say for sure unless we know what that it.

Comment: No not magic but C sharpe doesn't allow the concept of Nothing and object's don't do the same thing see the VB above, it works...so yes if you want to call it magic, your choice...